# mod_rewrite rule keeps in loop

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

I am doing a quite simple rule for mod_rewrite yet I get a loop
Here are the rules:

first if I have a request like

`index.php/SOMETHING.(txt,jpg,php)`

I need to first check if `/SOMETHING.(txt,jpg,png)` exists and display it

if the file is not an `index.php/SOMETING` and is a real path that exists display it

if not...pass it on to the `index.php/SOMETHING.(txt,jpg,php)` and show index.php

It all works but the last rule if I have a unexistent txt,jpg,php

example : `http://domain.com/index.php/robots1.txt`

File does not exist: `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/testredir/robots1.txt`

works for any other extension...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^index.php/.+$
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.+)\.jpg$ $1.jpg [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.+)\.txt$ $1.txt [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.+)\.php$ $1.php [NC,L]


#here I am missing a rule but if i put the following it will loop

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} -f
#RewriteRule .*  index.php/$0 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^index.php/.+$
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable always starts with a `/`, and you're matching  against it using `^index.php/.+$`, so that condition *will always be false*.

It looks like you want something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /index\.php/(.+)\.(jpg|txt|php)
RewriteRule ^ /%1.%2 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,PT]
```

Comment: wow, yes it works :)
what do I have to do if the file doesn't exist to actually redirect to index.php/$1 like http://domain.com/index.php/robots1.txt goes to http://domain.com/robots1.txt and it should stay the way it is..

Comment: @PartySoft that's what it should be doing, the first rule redirects it to `/robots.txt` and if that exists, the second rule never gets applied.

Comment: well it does show robots.txt if it exists , but if robots1.txt doesn't exists it goes in background to index.php but the url will be domain.com/robots1.txt, it doesn't stay as index.php/robots1.txt

Comment: @PartySoft The URL will stay `/robots1.txt` but the request gets routed to `index.php` silently